# Should I be using useState or setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function called myFunction that does not depend on anything. It simply generates a multidimensional array. Should I directly pass its return value to useState() or should I use setState()? Which is best practice and why?

A)

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const myFunction = () => {
    ...
    return someArrayOfArrays;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState(myFunction());

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

B)

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const myFunction = () => {
    ...
    return someArrayOfArrays;
  };

  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(myFunction());
  });

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: Both of those options use `useState()`. Are you asking whether you should use `useEffect()` to set the initial state?

Comment: If `myFunction()` is synchronous and is expected to always return the value value then I see no benefit to the second approach.  But if either of those cases is not true then the two approaches are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setValue(myFunction());
  },[]);
```

you need to put this [] in useEffect because you need to run it only one time.